# make transient column only when saving entity

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jsp

I have the next situation. I ahve entity object **User**:

```
package models;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.*;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Proxy;


@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@Proxy(lazy=true)
public class User {

    private int id;
    private String login;
    private String password;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private Integer age;
    private String country;
    private Set<UserRole> roles = new HashSet<UserRole>();
    private UserStatus status;
    private Date created;
    private Date updated;

    public User() {
        status=UserStatus.A;
    }

    public User(String user_login, String user_password, String user_name, String user_email) {
        this.login = user_login;
        this.password = user_password;
        this.name = user_name;
        this.email = user_email;
        status=UserStatus.A;
    }

    public User(String user_login, String user_password, String user_name, String user_email, int age) {
        this(user_login, user_password, user_name, user_email);
        this.age = age;
    }

    public User(String user_login, String user_password, String user_name, String user_email, int age, String country) {
        this(user_login, user_password, user_name, user_email, age);
        this.country = country;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="user_id", unique = true)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int user_id) {
        this.id = user_id;
    }

    @Column(name="user_login")
    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String user_login) {
        this.login = user_login;
    }

    @Column(name="user_password")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String user_password) {
        this.password = user_password;
    }

    @Column(name="user_name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String user_name) {
        this.name = user_name;
    }

    @Column(name="user_email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String user_email) {
        this.email = user_email;
    }

    @Column(name="user_age")
    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer user_age) {
        this.age = user_age;
    }

    @Column(name="user_country")
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String user_country) {
        this.country = user_country;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_to_userroles", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, 
                                            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_role_id ") })
    public Set<UserRole> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<UserRole> user_roles) {
        this.roles = user_roles;
    }

    @Column(name="user_status")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public UserStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(UserStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Transient
    @Column(name="user_created")
    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Date user_created) {
        this.created = user_created;
    }

    @Transient
    @Column(name="user_updated")
    public Date getUpdated() {
        return updated;
    }

    public void setUpdated(Date user_updated) {
        this.updated = user_updated;
    }

}
```

And *JSP page* (simple form, not related to question) with the form to create new user and table to show all existing users. I have used binding between form and Entity object **User** (it is inside controller):

```
User user = new User();
 List<User> users = userService.getAllUsers();//to fill table with users
 List<UserRole> userRoles = userRolesService.getAllRoles();//to fill tables with users

 model.addAttribute("rolesList", userRoles);
 model.addAttribute("users", users);
 model.put("adminForm", user);//Here adminForm is the name of form in JSP page
```

Now what is the problem: as you see **User** has two fields *user_created* and *user_updated* (they are created automatically by Postgres server). They are forwarded withh all other fields to table in JSP page. BUT my form in JSP does not provide these fields (no need - right)))), so they are null when transfered from form to controller. And now Hibernate can not add line on Postgres server because two fields are empty((( So my question is: 
can I somehow mark these columns as *@Transient* but only when I save entity not read it from database. 
I know I still can bind separate field in form not the whole object. But still is it possible to do what I ask? With existing configuration, new **User** is saved but these two fields are not read and JSP table columns are empty(((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the *insertable* and *updatable* properties of your column mapping to false. This will make the field read-only for Hibernate.

```
@Column(name="user_created", insertable=false, updatable=false)
```